# Proof that $a^n \ne b^{n+1}, (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: arithmetic

I was wondering if there exists a proof that:

$$a^n \ne b^{n+1},$$
$$a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$$

It would really help with a project that I am working on.

Thank you very much!

Comment: $8^2=4^3$, $16^3=8^4$, $32^4=16^5$, ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$8^4 = 4096 = 16^3$$
or in general, for any $k \in \mathbb N$,
$$ (k^n)^{n+1} = (k^{n+1})^n $$
gives a counterexample with $a = k^{n+1}$, $b = k^{n}$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am sorry that it was such an easily answered question!